# How to get nested Spel expression based objects through @ConfigurationProperties in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-el

This is in my `application.yml`

```yml
translations:
  en:
    title: 'english'
    description: 'english text'
  fr:
    title: 'french'
    description: 'french text'
  de:
    title: 'german'
    description: 'french text'

codes:
  GB:
    # I am assuming that en here will have an object with both title and description properties
    en: ${translations.en}
  CA:
    en: ${translations.en}
    fr: ${translations.fr}
  DE:
    en: ${translations.en}
    fr: ${translations.fr}
    de: ${translations.de}
```

Now consider this piece of code(removed unnecessary getters etc and also using [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) for brevity)

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    // Inner classes, but these can be outside as well
    @ConfigurationProperties
    @Getter
    @Component
    class Config {
        Map<String, Map<String, LanguageDTO>> codes;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    class LanguageDTO {
        String title;
        String description;
    }

    @Autowired
    Config config;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Getting error on this line below
        Map<String, Map<String, LanguageDTO>> codes = config.getCodes();
    }
}
```

Now when I start the app, I am getting an error like this:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'codes.gb.en' to com.example.demo.DemoApplication$LanguageDTO:

    Property: codes.gb.en
    Value: ${translations.en}
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml]:24:9
    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.example.demo.DemoApplication$LanguageDTO]

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

**What I want?**

I want to be able to read codes as a `Map<String, Map<String, LanguageDTO>`. That is, I should be able to do `config.getCodes().get("GB").get("en")` --> which should in turn have a data type of `LanguageDTO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's doable: Spring supports only simple property placeholders inside the application.yaml file (as far as I know). What you could do though, is leveraging YAML format built-in functionality, [anchors and aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Advanced_components):

```yml
translations:
  en: &en
    title: 'english'
    description: 'english text'
  fr: &fr
    title: 'french'
    description: 'french text'
  de: &de
    title: 'german'
    description: 'french text'

codes:
  GB:
    en: *en
  CA:
    en: *en
    fr: *fr
  DE:
    en: *en
    fr: *fr
    de: *de
```

> For it to work, the `LanguageDTO` class needs to have setters and a default constructor. @AllArgsConstructor won't work. Alternatively you might try to get it work in conjunction with [constructor binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConstructorBinding.html), although I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this and let you know. But wont `@Data` from lombok have `@Setter` annotation also? I might not need to add setters separately or use constructor binding.

Comment: Indeed, @Data adds setters but not default constructor which is required.